# Eclipse workspace configuration (maven) - how does it work?

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins

How does the maven task "mvn eclipse:eclipse" generate eclipse artifacts, and  How does it magically fix corrupt eclipse/mvn projects.  I haven't been able to detect exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates or updates .project, .classpath and .settings files from the pom.xml.

Comment: thats a correct answer :) some elaboration would be nice though.

Comment: You *can* use mvn eclipse:eclipse, but you should really consider using http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/ as it is much more fully featured. mvn eclipse:eclipse doesn't magically fix projects, in fact it will break projects created with m2eclipse. It merely recreates the files specified by greyfairer using data in the pom.xml. If you need more info, just open these files.